# How to handle replication post SQL Server 2000/2008 migration?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, migration, database-replication

I have two servers; server A host SQL Server 2000 and server B ( a remote server) host SQL Server 2005. I replicate data between these two servers using transactional replication. I recently migrated (side by side) the SQL server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 hosted on a virtual server. I would like to mimic the replication I already have between server A abd B. Can someone tell me the best practice of carrying out this task? Essentially, what I want to do is to set up a transactional replication between the SQL Server 2008 hosted on a virtual server and SQL Server 2005 hosted server B ( a remote server) . Do I have to create all the publications and subscriptions from scratch ? Thanks for your contribution in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so first of all here is the video tutorial for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbrUtfkkVUE

But before jumping on it, please consider reading the [Selecting the Appropriate Type of Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - maybe, Snapshot replication will fit you better for some reason.

If you are completely sure that Transactional replication is the way to go for you. check official [Considerations for Transactional Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151254(v=sql.105).aspx)

Hope that helped